# How to make subdomain using htaccess in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

With the code I wrote.

```
page.domain.com #URL

www.domain.com/page #Turns into URL
```

I want it the exact opposite.

```
www.domain.com/page #URL

page.domain.com #Turns into URL
```

How can i do it with htacces. My experiments have an endless loop.
I use Wordpress.

Comment: I can not write a domain because the address is forbidden.
The htacces code writes the domain before http.
Please note.